# How to obtain early version of Opera browser source code?

Tags: browser, open-source, opera

My project requires me to run a web browser with a customized openssl on windows.
And after searching for a while, I can only find earlier version (<=version 12.18) of opera browser desktop version is using openssl.

But I can not find the source code of it. Because we need to compile and let the browser link to our own openssl library.

Can anyone tell me where I can download the source code of earlier version of Opera, which does not use Chromium as its core?

Or please kindly let me know if you know any simple browser running on windows uses openssl as its ssl library.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Opera Presto source code [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/prestocore/browser).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @niutech ! I will check it out soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of Presto-based versions of Opera is not publicly available.